# Sin x tends to x as x tends to zero

Tags: trigonometry

If ABC is a sector of a circle with centre A, why does the area of triangle ABC approach the area of sector ABC as angle BAC approaches zero?

Comment: What do you mean by that it "approaches" the area of sector $ABC$?  Since both areas are approaching zero, it is obvious that they approach each other.  Do you mean that they approximate each other to some degree?  Or the ratio approaches zero?

Comment: Why is it 'obvious'?

Comment: If two numbers are approaching zero, then they approach each other also.

Comment: You need to clarify what it means for an area to "approach" a different area, because in mathematics there are many different notions of "approach".

Comment: Also in my previous comment, I meant "the ratio approaches one".  Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if the angle at the centre is $\theta$ measured in radians, and the radius is $r$ then the area of the sector is $\cfrac {r^2\theta}2$.

The area of the triangle is calculated by taking $D$ as the midpoint of $BC$ so that $AD=r\cos\frac{\theta}2$ and $BC=2r\sin\frac{\theta}2$. The area is then $\frac 12 AD\cdot BC=\frac{r^2\sin \theta}2$.

Extending $AD$ to meet the circle at $E$ and taking the tangent at $E$ to meet $AB$ at $F$ and $AC$ at $G$, $AFG$ is similar to $ABC$, with the sides longer by a factor of $\frac 1{\cos {\frac{\theta}2}}$ so we get $$\frac{r^2\sin \theta}2\lt\cfrac {r^2\theta}2\lt\frac 1{\cos^2 {\frac{\theta}2}}\cdot\frac{r^2\sin \theta}2$$

Since $\frac 1{\cos^2 {\frac{\theta}2}}$ is approximately $1$ for small values of $\theta$, the two outside expressions become close to one another - you can make this as precise as you need.